# Como abrir uma nova activity sem fechar o menu drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Tenho uma activity e nessa activity tenho o menu drawer. Como que faz para chamar uma outra activity sem que o menu drawer suma? 
Só quero alterar o content da activity. 
Tentei utilizar fragment mas ele não apaga o que já está na tela, ele  insere uma nova activity.

Comment: Não dá pra fazer isso... terá que usar fragments para mudar o conteúdo.

Comment: Como assim? não entendi. @Luc. Tem diversos apps que ao entrar vc tem um "menu"  para navegar no app e o menu drawer. Queria que esse espaço onde fica o menu fosse alterado quando eu clicasse nele sem que o menu drawer sumisse. Tem como?

Comment: Se eu não estiver entendido errado, são fragments... Cada item do menu drawer é um fragment, então se você clica no item 'home', abre o fragment, se você clica em 'settings', abre o fragment 'settings' e assim por diante...

Comment: @Luc muito obrigado, está me salvando.

Answer (score -1):

Cria dois arquivos para sua nova **activity** um arquivo **java** e a outra é uma **content_nome.xml** dentro da **content_nome.xml** você coloca o comando *`<include layout="SeuDrawer.xml>"*`

RECOMENDO: primeiro faça tudo que tem que fazer na content por ultimo add o drawer ela atrapalha um pouco kk pq ela fica aberta